# How can I make the sample projects for Qualcomm Snapdragon run on Android emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am trying [Qualcomm Snapdragon SDK](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/snapdragon-sdk-android/download). I am successful with compiling and building the sample projects, for example, the audio SDK sample, in Eclipse with ADT.

In addition I installed Qualcomm SDK package in SDK manager according to the guide given on Qualcomm website. I run the project with Qualcomm customized target (when configuring the virtual device, you may specify Qualcomm as the target rather than native API 15 and the like).

But the features that ought to be available are all shown to be 'unsupported', according to the run output of the app.

Comment: well maybe that's their fault. what does the demo (supposed to ) do , btw?

Comment: They're actually samples for APIs from Qcom Snapdragon SDK. According to the documentation, the APIs demonstrate QSD features, such as extra CODECS, additional sensors, Zero-Sutter-Lag, etc. I thought that the sample apps would yield feature-supported results for QSD-powered virtual devices (with QSD as the VD target) while they would generate feature-unsupported results for standard android VDs (with standard Android API level as the VD target).  But no matter how I set the target for the VD, the Qcom sample apps just show "feature unsupported".

Comment: maybe try to run the samples on a device that has snapdragon? i wonder if that's the reason.

Comment: I also want to try that. But the documentation states that it requires a MSM8960 with android ICS. I have some QSD mobiles with Android 2.x, but I don't have newer models as required by the QSD SDK.

Comment: what's MSM8960 ? also , about the version , you could install a custom ROM , depending on your device (of course ,you will have to root it) .

Comment: MSM8960 is a high-end chipset from Qualcomm Inc., included in its Snapdragon (QSD) S4 series. It's a pity that I don't have a REAL device currently. As a result I have to rely on Android Virtual Device.

Comment: yes , i'm not sure how well does android emulator works currently . quite a long time ago (maybe on 2010) i remember that google has promised that the emulator will work much better and faster , but i still don't see almost any improvement of it.